# Is func() + func() undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior

I only know `i = i++;` is *undefined behavior*, but if there are two or more functions called in an *expression*, and all the functions are the same. Is it *undefined*? For example:

```
int func(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func(0) + func(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i=i++ is not undefined... as far as i know anyway.

Comment: I think it's *unspecified* behavior.

Comment: @thang: `i = i++` has undefined behavior. When a program both modifies and separately accesses a scalar object without an intervening sequence point, the C++ standard does not define the behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The behavior of the expression `func(0) + func(1)` is defined in that the result will be the sum of the results obtained by calling `func` with a parameter of `0` and `func`with a parameter of `1`.

However, the order in which the functions are called is probably [implementation dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/56778), although it might be unspecified. That is, the compiler could generate code equivalent to:

```
int a = func(0);
int b = func(1);
int result = a + b;
```

Or it could generate:

```
int a = func(1);
int b = func(0);
int result = a + b;
```

This normally won't be a problem unless `func` has side effects that depend on the order of calls.

Comment: Or `func(0)` and `func(1)` could execute in parallel, and assuming a thread-safe `cout`, the output could be `10\n\n1\n`.

Comment: @KenY-N: True enough.

Comment: Does this mean that if I change a global variable `i` in `func`, the result of `i` is undefined ?

Comment: If `func` contained the statement `i = a;` where `i` was a global, then the value of `i` after the statement in `main` would be implementation dependent. It could be `0` or it could be `1`, depending on which function call was executed last.

Comment: @KenY-N, no the calls can not occur in parallel.  If calling func() set a global variable, this would introduce a data-race, which would inject undefined behavior into the program.  Since many function calls access or modify global state (especially if they're written for a single thread of execution), this would break all kinds of programs.

Comment: @user2482012 Note that all side effects of statements are completed before the next statement is executed. So modifying `i` within `func` won't cause undefined behavior.

Comment: The compiler could also generate `if (PhaseOfMoon() > 0.5) { ... func(0) first ...} else { ... func(1) first ...}`.  The astronomical calculations would be unlikely of course, but a compiler which was e.g. unrolling a loop might discover that the first iteration could benefit from evaluating its operands in a different sequence from later ones, so repeated execution *of the same piece of code* may not yield consistent sequence.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of this program is not [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) but it is [unspecified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior), if we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `1.9` *Program execution* paragraph *15* says(*emphasis mine*):

> **Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced**. [ Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently in different evaluations. —end note ] The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar
>   object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

and if we check section `5.7` *Additive operators* which covers `+` and `-` that section does not specify an ordering so it is unsequenced.

In this case `func` has a side effect since it is outputting to `stdout` and so the order of the output is going to depend on the implementation and it even could change for subsequent evaluations.

Note that the `;` ends an *expression statement* and section `6.2` *Expression statement* says:

> [...]All side effects from an expression statement are completed before the next statement is executed.[...]

so although the order of the function calls is unspecified, the side effects of each statement are completed before the next.

Comment: Another key is later in 1.9p15, where it says: "Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) [...] is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function." As p13 defines, that means "A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified which." This is important, because while the part from 6.2 you quoted (and also 1.9p14) says that the single `cout`s in the two functions cannot mingle, it would not prevent multiple `cout`s in the two functions to interleave.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::cout << func(0) + func(1) << std::endl;
```

Whether the function call `func(0)` or `func(1)` executes first, is implementation dependent. After that, there is a sequence point, and `func(0) + func(1)` is output.

But by definition, it's not called undefined behavior.