# What is the "critical section" of _Atomic in C11

Tags: c, atomic

Per this [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic), for `_Atomic int a`, `++a`/`a++`/`a %= 2`/etc are all atomic. But problem is, will the following expression:

```
_Atomic size_t thread_counter = 0;
void thread_counting() {
  int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;
}
```

be as "atomic" as if it is implemented using `mutex`?:

```
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
size_t thread_counter = 0;
void thread_counting() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex); // assume pthread_mutex_lock() always success
  int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}
```

The wording of C11 standard is a bit too esoteric for me and I failed to get a concrete answer from it. I prepared the following code to test this hypothesis, the result appears to suggest that the answer is affirmative, but not sure if there are any big flaws in it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 5000
#define PASS_NUM 128
_Atomic uint8_t *table = NULL;
_Atomic size_t thread_counter = 0;
_Atomic short error = 0;

void *counting(void *pass) {
  uint8_t p = *((uint8_t *)pass);
  if (error) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;
  // Alternative implementation, breaks atomicity:
  // thread_counter = (thread_counter + 1) % THREAD_NUM;
  // int execution_id = thread_counter;
  if (table[execution_id] == p) {
    table[execution_id] = p + 1;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: table[%d]==%u, expecting %u\n", execution_id,
            table[execution_id], p);
    ++error;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void test_concurrent_counting() {
  table = (_Atomic uint8_t *)calloc(THREAD_NUM, sizeof(short));
  if (table == NULL) {
    perror("calloc()");
    goto err_calloc_table;
  }
  pthread_t *ths = (pthread_t *)calloc(THREAD_NUM, sizeof(pthread_t));
  if (table == NULL) {
    perror("malloc()");
    goto err_malloc_pthread;
  }

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < PASS_NUM && error == 0; ++i) {
    printf("Pass no.%u\n", i);
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < THREAD_NUM; ++j) {
      if (pthread_create(&ths[j], NULL, counting, &i) != 0) {
        // this error handling might not be perfect
        --j;
        perror("pthread_create()");
        break;
      }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= j; ++k) {
      (void)pthread_join(ths[k], NULL);
    }
  }

  free(ths);
err_malloc_pthread:
  free(table);
err_calloc_table:
  return;
}

int main(void) { 
  test_concurrent_counting();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of lock-free atomics is atomicity as a primitive operation, *not* via a critical section.  (See [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) for how it works under the hood.) But yes, for `seq_cst` atomics at least, the observable behaviours are probably limited to those you could get if there was a hidden lock.  For non-lock-free atomics (with `.is_always_lock_free` is false), there actually is a mutex or spinlock: [Where is the lock for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50298358)

Comment: @PeterCordes i am not sure if I make myself clear in the question, I mean to say "whether or not the lock-free version is as 'atomic' as if I use mutex (i.e., with critical section)". For sure there isn't really a critical section, just I am wondering if the observable result would be the same.

Comment: Ok, from comments under Renat's answer, you seem to be asking whether the modulo happens as if part of the atomic operation, as if in a critical section.  It doesn't, it's totally separate.  But that doesn't matter, because only the `atomic_fetch_add` (`++`) itself needs to be atomic to derive unique counters from `THREAD_NUM` contiguous integers via modulo.  Computations on local vars and temporaries are per-thread private so are unaffected by other threads computing stuff from their `atomic_fetch_add` result in parallel.

Comment: @PeterCordes then how about `int execution_id = ((thread_counter++) + ((thread_counter++)) % THREAD_NUM;`? Now we have two `thread_count++`s, does this make it not "thread-safe"? (I am even not sure if "thread-safe" is still the appropriate term to use--i have the feeling that it is just the result may be unexpected, but it is perfectly well-defined and thread-safe...)

Comment: @DJ - Using two atomic operations is not atomic as a whole, as other threads might run between them. So you *could* get counters 3 and 9.

Comment: Well you're not guaranteed to get two consecutive counts; if your algorithm relied on that, you'd say it wasn't "thread safe" and should be using `(thread_count+=2) * 2 - 3` or something.

Comment: I thought about using an example like that, but didn't want to bring up something with two indeterminately-sequenced `++` side-effects on the same object.  Note that `i++  + i++` is UB for non-_Atomic `int i`, and maybe also `_Atomic int i`.  If that's not sequencing UB, at best the two `++` operations are indeterminately sequenced wrt. each other in the same thread, a non-commutative op like `shared++ - shared++` could get positive or negative depending on how it compiled.  But `+` is commutative so order doesn't matter.

Comment: Other than possible sequencing UB (*[Is int a = ++i + ++i undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61264384)*), `int tmp1 = thread_counter++;` / `int tmp2 = thread_counter++;` / `id = (tmp1 + tmp2) % THREAD_NUM;` would be exactly equivalent to your single-statement version.  Being in the same expression doesn't glue two atomic operations together into a single transaction, even on the same variable.

Comment: @PeterCordes then how about this? `int execution_d = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM + (first_func() << 2) % (second_func(local_var1) | third_func(local_var2, local_var3))`? Is it that as long as the `_Atomic` variable appears "only once", no matter how long my statement goes, the entire statement is still as protected as if I have a "critical section"?

Comment: *the entire statement is still as protected as if I have a "critical section"?*  - No, of course not.  If any of those other functions access any other shared memory, that's separate from the  `thread_counter++` access.  If not, they don't need to be inside a critical section, and more code in the same expression as the atomic `++` won't make contention worse by "holding the lock" for longer.  Only the access to shared data needs to be atomic so there's no problem with "unlocking early", before computation on locals, as long as those other functions don't access other shared memory.

Comment: `thread_counter++` is defined as being equivalent to `atomic_fetch_add(&thread_counter)`.  The "critical section" or equivalent exists only inside the `atomic_fetch_add` function.  (It will actually inline to `lock xadd [RIP + thread+counter], eax` or something like that, with atomicity guaranteed by hardware just for that atomic increment.)

Comment: @PeterCordes on UB of `int a = ++i + ++i`, if I follow the argument correctly, `int a = ++i + (b * ++i)` will be well defined as two `++i` are "sequenced". Does this make sense to you?

Comment: No, operator precedence is separate from happens-before / sequenced-before.  (In the pre-C++11 notion of "sequence points", evaluation of binary `*` isn't a sequence point.)  See [What made i = i++ + 1; legal in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47702220) for some discussion of the formal rules.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah yes, I just get the point. What do you think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401857/does-int-sum-func1-func2-cause-undefined-behavior-if-func-modifies-a-g)?

Comment: "indeterminately sequenced" (one then the other, but compiler's choice which) is separate from "unsequenced" (potentially overlapping).  Two function calls in the same expression not separated by sequence points are indeterminately-sequenced.  Even after inlining, the compiler isn't allowed to interleave their side-effects, except in ways that can't make an observable difference (the as-if rule)  That's what the answer explains on that Q&A you linked, isn't it?

Comment: You edited your comment while I was replying.  You'd first linked [Is func() + func() undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18907342) which has an answer from Shafik Yaghmour that uses the technical terminology of "indeterminately sequenced".  Your new question is probably a duplicate of that, or of similar questions about unsequenced vs. indeterminately-sequenced.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is thread safe, given `THREAD_NUM` is constant. Because in

```
int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;
```

`execution_id` - is a local variable, so it's not shared between threads.
And `thread_counter++` operation on shared variable `thread_counter` is atomic by its `_Atomic` declaration, thus concurrent threads cannot see it partially executed.

So it's an equivalent to

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex); // assume pthread_mutex_lock() always success
int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
```

Comment: this comes to another question, can I say that "as long as I have one semicolon only and there is no function call, the expression is as thread-safe as if it is protected by a mutex"? I hesitate a lot while using `_Atomic` because I am not sure if all possible combinations of operations in one statement are always guaranteed to be atomic...

Comment: Generally speaking  - no. Expression with single semicolon still can have multiple side effects, visible by concurrent threads. In this particular code, because `int execution_id = (thread_counter++) % THREAD_NUM;` involves local variable and a constant, side effects could be reduced to just `thread_counter++`, which is atomic

Comment: Is there any authoritative source where I can look up whether some operations are thread-safe or not? Otherwise one can misuse `_Atomic` very easily

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, I'm not an expert in this topic. I would suggest to start from Wikipedia page, and may be check external links and references there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: The ISO C standard is the ultimate authority, of course, clearly stating that each separate operation on an `_Atomic` object is separately atomic.  For example, `foo = foo + 1;` is not an atomic RMW on `foo`, it's a separate load and store.  But `foo += 1` or `++foo` is one atomic RMW, so 100 of them will ultimately produce 100 increments, no matter which threads do it.  As https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread puts it, *Each atomic operation is indivisible with regards to any other atomic operation that involves the same object. Atomic objects are free of data races.*

Comment: It does also depend on the ISA. If there's no support for atomic 32 bit access in the ISA, then there's no C magic that can save the day. Or if read-modify-write instructions aren't guaranteed to be atomic on the ISA level. Etc etc. Meaning that you shouldn't be messing around with `_Atomic` unless you are writing fairly low-level code, which you verify through disassembly.

Comment: @Lundin: If the ISA can't support lock-free operations for a certain type `T`, use of `_Atomic T` will result in locking around operations on it.  Exactly the same as in [Where is the lock for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50298358), using the same compiler internals.  The atomicity / ordering / correctness guarantees in the ISO C standard for UB-free programs all still apply, the only thing you lose is performance.  (And address-freedom, so it's not safe in shared memory between processes.  Also of course not atomic wrt. other hardware things outside this C program since it's ju

Comment: @Lundin: So I'd say precisely the opposite: `_Atomic T` is good for any `T` where most ISAs can handle it as lock-free, *except* for low-level code where you care how it gets atomicity.  In that case you can just check the asm, or call https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free or `#if ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/ATOMIC_LOCK_FREE_consts)

Comment: @PeterCordes Imagine a lousy 8-bit microcontroller and you declare an `_Atomic uint32_t` - that's just senseless. There's no OS, no mutex/critical section etc - there exists no lock.

Comment: @Lundin: Spinlocks are always possible, although pointless on a single-core system so like I said, you'd want to check `#if ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE` before using `_Atomic unsigned long` between a main thread and an interrupt handler.  Non-lock-free code could deadlock if the interrupt handler tries to take the lock (access the atomic) while the main thread holds the lock (was in the middle of an `_Atomic` operation).  I'd call that pretty low-level, writing your own interrupt handlers on bare metal, not user-space under an OS (non-low-level) where `_Atomic` is fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes And yet you might want to use `_Atomic` on such low-level code, to ensure that the correct assembler instructions are picked. Because just using `uint8_t` in C on an 8-bit MCU is no guarantee of atomicity. The compiler might generate code like "push register on stack", "modify stack" in 2 instructions. But if told to keep it `_Atomic` it might decide to reserve a register etc, so that modifications of the value are single instruction.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, then you're into "have to check the asm" territory.  Or stick to types that are lock-free.  I didn't say you couldn't use `_Atomic` at all in "low-level" code where the asm details matter, just that you do have to check for at least lock-freedom, and maybe for implementation details.

Comment: @Lundin Since `_Atomic` is from C standard, with ISA or not, a standard-compliant compiler should give me `_Atomic`, even if internally it may use `mutex` or other hardware-specific tricks to achieve the same effect. If some platform doesnt have necessary hardware synchronization support at all, then I believe the C compilers on that platform have no choice but define `_ _STDC_NO_ATOMICS_ _` and my code will just not compile.